# Joining on column names with spaces

Tags: join, proc-sql

I'm trying to join to tables using PROQ SQL. One of the columns I'm using for the join has a space in the column name. The query I'm using:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TEST AS
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TABLE_1 a
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 b
ON a.CONTNO = b."Contract Number";
RUN;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, *.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add square brackets around the Column name.  For example:
b.[Contract Number]

Tips:  Using alias (a, b) can be costly.  When you only have one table to join, consider typing out the table rather than doing an alias.